# Why do most columns from target site not show up in a look up column?

Tags: custom-list, lookup-column

I have list A where I am trying to look up information in list B.  However only a limited number of columns are available, basically only the out of the box columns.  None of my custom columns show up as available for look up.

Answer (score 2):

Only certain field types can be used in lookup columns. They are most typically only single lines of text fields that can be used as the lookup source, but number or date fields can be used too.

[image]
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80A3E0A6-8016-41FB-AD09-8BF16D490632